# Convert forms with inputs that have same name to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, parsing

I have a form like so that collects information about a users car:

```
<form id="car" action="" method="">
    <section class="inputContainer">
        <section class="carInfo">
            <input type="text" name="Make" class="make" />
            <input type="text" name="Model" class="model" />
            <input type="text" name="Year" class="year" />
            <input type="text" name="Color" class="color" />
        </section>
    </section>
    <input type="hidden" name="AllCarData" />
    <a class="addAnotherCar" href="#">Add another car</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When the user clicks the 'Add another car' link, my JS duplicates the 'carInfo' group of inputs and appends it to 'inputContainer'; creating a new set of form inputs like so:

```
<form id="car" action="" method="">
    <section class="inputContainer">
        <section class="carInfo">
            <input type="text" name="Make" class="make" />
            <input type="text" name="Model" class="model" />
            <input type="text" name="Year" class="year" />
            <input type="text" name="Color" class="color" />
        </section>
        <section class="carInfo">
            <input type="text" name="Make" class="make" />
            <input type="text" name="Model" class="model" />
            <input type="text" name="Year" class="year" />
            <input type="text" name="Color" class="color" />
        </section>
    </section>
    <input type="hidden" name="AllCarData" />
    <a class="addAnotherCar" href="#">Add another car</a>
</form>
```

Once the user clicks submit, I want to parse the form into a JSON object and inject it into a hidden input field. JSON for two cars should look like this:

```
[{ "Make" : "Mazda" , "Model":  "Protege" , "Year" : "2002" , "Color" : "Red" } , { "Make" : "Toyota" , "Model":  "Camery" , "Year" : "2012" , "Color" : "Blue" }]
```

I am currently getting the input's name to serve as the key and the entered value as the value. I have the following function built:

```
CreateJson: function () {
        $.fn.serializeObject = function()
        {
            var o = {};
            var a = this.serializeArray();
            $.each(a, function() {
                if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
            });
            return o;
        };

        var carDataString = JSON.stringify($('.inputContainer input').serializeObject());
        console.log(carDataString);
        $("input[name='AllCarData']").val(carDataString);
    }

};
```

********The only problem is that since the additional inputs that are duplicated when a user chooses to add another car use the same 'name', my JSON is only outputting one set of values insead of multiple (when multiple cars are added). http://jsfiddle.net/njacoy/jLopamk7/

Note: I am using the jQuery validate plugin to validate this form. It's set to look for input names.

Thanks!

Comment: If I were You I would create objects of this data, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Comment: Instead of selecting `inputContainer input`, you should iterate over `carInfo`s and create a separate object for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
 $.fn.serializeObject  = function (data) {
        var els = $(this).find(':input').get();
        if (typeof data != 'object') {
            // return all data
            data = {};
            $.each(els, function () {
                if (this.name && !this.disabled && (this.checked || /select|textarea/i.test(this.nodeName) || /text|hidden|password/i.test(this.type))) {
                    data[this.name] = $(this).val();
                }
            });
            return data;
        }
    };


$("#car").submit(function () {
    var data = [];
    $(this).find(".inputContainer section").each(function () {
       data[data.length] = $(this).serializeObject();
    })
    var carDataString=JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(carDataString);
    $("input[name='AllCarData']").val(carDataString);
    return false
});
```

here's the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/jLopamk7/4/

Comment: This works great! However, is there a way to get it to work on click instead of on submit? Just wondering because I may have to do the same for another form that is broken down into different steps. For example, I'd like to collect the data on step 2 of a form when the user clicks the 'Next' button to go to step 3.

Comment: bind click event with submit event eg- instead of $("#car").submit(function () {---code----}) do $("#yourNextButton").click(function () {---code----}). Heres the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/jLopamk7/5/

Comment: @NickJ If my answer suited your needs, don't forget to accept it (same for the other questions you asked :)

Answer (score 0):

You would serialise the inputs in each section separately, then get them as an array and use `stringify` on that:

```
var carDataString = JSON.stringify(
  $('.inputContainer section').map(function(i, o){
    return o.find('input').serializeObject();
  }).get()
);
```